# Why am I getting Can't find string terminator "'" error when I run Perl one liner on Windows

Tags: windows, perl

i want to print the yesterday's date from a perl one liner, when i run this in command prompt, i get the below error.

```
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); 
         $now_string = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime(time()-86400); 
         print $now_string';
```

Error:

```
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

My perl version v5.14.2

Comment: The trailing semicolon is unnecessary.

Comment: Never seen a one-liner with 3 lines. :-)

Comment: @Francisco Zarabozo, The editor added the line breaks for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Single-quotes (`'`) are meaningless to the Windows command shell. Arguments are quoted using double-quotes (`"`).

   If you want a double-quote string literal (e.g. `"\n"`) need double-quotes within the argument, you can use `qq{...}` instead (`qq{\n}`).
2. Your code doesn't always return yesterday's date. Because some days have more than 86400 seconds, you could get the date of the day before yesterdays. Because some days have less than 86400 seconds, you could get today's date. You want:

   ```
   perl -MDateTime -E"say
      DateTime->now(time_zone=>'local')->set_time_zone('floating')
      ->subtract(days=>1)->strftime('%Y%m%d')"
   ```

   You'll have to put it all on one line, though, because the Windows command shell doesn't support line breaks in its arguments.

Comment: thanks.. I need to install the datetime module and i will try it.

Comment: I actually like to think of `"\n"` as an shortcut of `qq"\n"`. Same with `' '` and `q' '`.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, on the Windows command line, you have to use double quotes:

```
perl -e "..."
```

If the command you're running needs quoting on the inside, use `''` or `qq{}`.

```
perl -e "print qq{Hello Windows\n}"
```